# Serving a binary file

Tags: python, html, flask

I have the following Flask app:

```
@app.route('/')
def serve_index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/binary/')
def serve_binary():
    file_name, file_path = generate_binary()
    return send_file(file_path, attachment_filename = file_name, as_attachment=True)
```

If I go to `localhost/` I get the index.html as expected.

If I go to `localhost/binary/` I get the binary file as expected.

(`generate_binary()` is a Python script I wrote, which generates a binary, stores it in a folder Flask has access to and returns the filename as well as the path to the file).

Now I want to write a link into the index.html which lets me download the binary I get, if I visit `localhost/binary/`.

My index.html looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="localhost/binary/" target="blank">Link to binary</a>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if I visit `localhost/` and click the `Link to binary` link I get to `localhost/binary/` but have to reload this page in order to get the binary file.

What I want is to just get the file, without leaving the `index.html` page.

Comment: `localhost/binary` is still a relative path, not a full URL. Did you mean to use `http://localhost/binary` perhaps? That'll go to the default port, 80.

Comment: You are telling the browser to open a new window (`target="blank"` is misspelled, it'll re-use the same window each time, you probably meant `_blank`). You shouldn't really do that to download a file.

Comment: Using `http://localhost/binary` and deleting `target="_blank"` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`localhost/binary` is a *relative path*, not a full URL. Use one of:

- `{{ url_for('serve_binary') }}` -- Ask Flask to generate the URL
- `http://localhost/binary`  -- an absolute URL with hostname
- `/binary`-- the absolute path only

Next, you are asking the browser to open the download in a new window or tab named `blank`. There are two issues with this; the normal name to open a new unnamed window or tab is `_blank` (note the underscore), and for a *download* you'd not want to open a whole new tab. Remove the `target="..."` attribute there.